FFT of time varying measured signal in python
I am currently trying to measure the FFT of the measured signals (shown below) at the input of my device.

I am currently following the method detailed in this article, and wrote the following code to analyze the FFT of both the signals
volt = buff1 - np.mean(buff1)
curr = buff2 - np.mean(buff2)
N = len(volt)
norm = N/2

# Get the frequency components of the spectrum
sampling_rate = 15.6e6 
freq_axis = rfftfreq(N, d=1/sampling_rate)
signal_amp = 2*np.abs(rfft(volt))/N
signal_amp1 = 2*np.abs(rfft(curr))/N

fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_subplot(111, label ='1')
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(111, label = '2', frame_on = False)

ax.plot(freq_axis,signal_amp)
ax.set_xlim(0,20000)
ax.set_ylabel("y label 1")
ax.yaxis.set_label_position('left') 

ax2.plot(freq_axis,signal_amp1, color="C1")
ax2.set_xlim(0,20000)
ax2.set_ylabel("y label 2", color="C1")
ax2.yaxis.tick_right()
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', colors="C1")
ax2.yaxis.set_label_position('right') 

plt.show()

and the output is shown as below,

I have 2 problems here,

The peak frequency should be at 60Hz but somehow it is closer to 6kHz
Every time, I read the signals from the buffer, the waveform changes and I am unable to fix the length of the buffer to exactly capture the same type of waveform, for example, I could be reading a different phase shifted waveform (same frequency and peak) like this..


I believe, I should be applying a windowing type of method, where I would sample one or two full period of signals instead of whole length of buffer. Is my understanding correct? Any help with correcting both the issues in the code is really appreciated.
Thank you very much in advance.
Edit-1: The signals measured in the scope application for reference,


Taking a rough look at your input signal, it does indeed seem to be a signal that has a frequency of around 6 kHz, assuming the sampling rate you specify is correct.
Did the estimate by looking at the last two peaks, which seem to be separated by about 2,500 samples. If $f_s = 15.6 \ MHz$, then the sinusoid frequency is approximately
$$f_0 = \frac{15.6 \ MHz}{2500} \approx 6240 \ Hz$$
I added the sinusoid generation to your code and did some small changes below:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f0 = 6000  # Hz
sampling_rate = 15.6e6

# Generate time array
t = np.arange(0, (1/sampling_rate)*12000, 1/sampling_rate)

buff1 = 0.88 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * f0 * t)
buff2 = 0.63 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * f0 * t)

volt = buff1 - np.mean(buff1)
curr = buff2 - np.mean(buff2)
N = len(volt)
norm = N/2

# Get the frequency components of the spectrum
freq_axis = np.fft.rfftfreq(N, 1/sampling_rate)
signal_amp = 2*np.abs(np.fft.rfft(volt, N))/N
signal_amp1 = 2*np.abs(np.fft.rfft(curr, N))/N

fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_subplot(111, label ='1')
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(111, label = '2', frame_on = False)

ax.plot(freq_axis,signal_amp)
ax.set_xlim(0,20000)
ax.set_ylabel("y label 1")
ax.yaxis.set_label_position('left')

ax2.plot(freq_axis,signal_amp1, color="C1")
ax2.set_xlim(0,20000)
ax2.set_ylabel("y label 2", color="C1")
ax2.yaxis.tick_right()
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', colors="C1")
ax2.yaxis.set_label_position('right')

plt.show()

Which produces the following plot, showing a peak at about where you expect:

Also, I recommend you set the parameter $N$ to something much larger, and pass it to rfft(), so that the frequency spacing of the DFT is smaller so you can get a better representation of the signal. For example, setting $N$ to be 20 times larger, you get this:

Are you sure you are using the correct sampling rate?

Thank you so much for your analysis and helping me in understanding the issue. I used the sampling rate of 15.6 MS/s from the decimation used by the ADC. Now, that you rightly pointed out and calculated from the buffer information (which I should've cross checked too), I do believe that there is something missing that I am not familiar with.
I will reach out to the OEM for clarification on buffer length and sampling rate details. The same signals when I measured through their scope application, the frequency is measured as 60Hz (I added the scope picture in edit for your quick reference).

@Kali Look at the bottom right of the scope picture, it tells you the sample rate. Using that will get you what is expected.
